# VSTS Releases started failing unexpectedly due to the 6h timeout

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We are experiencing issues with the VSRM deployment where deployments started unexpectedly failing due to the 6h timeout. The job timeout we have specified in our phase is 24h but it fails after 6h. Can you please share what should I do to come out of it?

**Issues in the release**

The job has exceeded the maximum allowed time of 06:00:00. Please visit …. for more information

The agent has received a shutdown signal. This can happen when the agent service is stopped, or a manually started agent is canceled.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, seems you are actually using **Microsoft-hosted CI/CD**.

If you are running builds and releases with hosted pipelines, which means the build running 
on machines managed by Microsoft.

This uses our [pool of Microsoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=vsts) to run your builds, which do have some limitations such as below:

The ability to log on.

- The ability to drop artifacts to a UNC file share.
- The ability to run XAML builds.
- Potential performance advantages that you might get by using
  self-hosted agents which might start and process builds faster. Learn
  more

> We provide a **free tier** of service by default in your VSTS
>   organization, allowing you to run one concurrent job for up to 240
>   minutes per month. This uses our pool of Microsoft-hosted agents to
>   run your builds and releases. Each build or release job can run for up
>   to 30 minutes.
>
> When the free tier of Microsoft-hosted CI/CD is no longer sufficient,
>   you can pay for CI/CD capacity per concurrent job. **Paid
>   Microsoft-hosted CI/CD removes the monthly time limit and also allows
>   you to run a single job for up to 6 hours.**

In your case, if your could not reduce the time of your single job, you have to use **Self-hosted CI/CD**. You'll start by deploying our [self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/agents?view=vsts#install) on your machines. More details about related info please refer this official tutorial -- **[CI/CD Concurrent Jobs in Team Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs-vsts?view=vsts#self-hosted-cicd)**

Answer (score -1):

This happens when the deployment is running on Microsoft hosted agent as it has a max timeout of 6 hours for a single job. See this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/visual-studio-team-services/) for more details.